# Whenever I am trying to install skype or google talk

Tags: 12.04

Whenever I am trying to install skype or google talk , after downloading from internet when I am trying to open with software centre they says [image: This shows]
,

I am using ubuntu 12.04, 64 bit

Comment: Welcome to AU! Can you please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/532789/edit) your question to describe how you're trying to install Skype and Google Talk? The software center appears to be invoked with a link to a local file as search term, which doesn't amount to much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's maybe because they don't exist in the Software Centre in the first place.
But what you could do is instead install them with the terminal. If it's .deb packets you have downloaded you could just type `dpkg -i <packagename>.deb` to install it.
You have to of course stand in the same directory as your downloaded file (probably /home/yourusername/Downloads/).

`dpkg` is the Debian package manager tool that is used to install `.deb` packages. The flag `-i` means install. If you want to remove/uninstall a package you can use the flag `-r` (dpkg -r).

Comment: thaanks I  dont know much commands, yes it is in my download folder, could you please write the whole commands which I can copy and paste in terminal to download ;) ?

Comment: @UneFemmeDouce I Could, but you have to give me the whole file names of the downloaded files.

Comment: google-talkplugin_current_amd64.deb

Comment: @UneFemmeDouce First open a terminal. Type `cd /home/yourusername/Downloads` now your are inside your downloads folder. Then type `dpkg -i google-talkplugin_current_amd64.deb` to install it.

Comment: bash: cd/home/ramen/Downloads: No such file or directory
..this is the mssge I am getting when I write cd... as U said

Comment: @UneFemmeDouce Are you forgetting a space between `cd` and `/home/ramen/Downloads`?

Comment: :-o :-o .............okay i am trying again

Comment: now they are saying dpkg: error: requested operation requires superuser privilege

Comment: @UneFemmeDouce Add `sudo` infront of the command to access superuser privileges. `sudo dpkg -i google-talkplugin_current_amd64.deb`

Comment: thank uuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu

Comment: @UneFemmeDouce Marks my answer above as correct and we're even (the checkmark). ;)

Comment: hey sure, but while installing skype they gives dpkg: error processing skype-ubuntu-precise_4.3.0.37-1_i386.deb.deb (--install):
 cannot access archive: No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 skype-ubuntu-precise_4.3.0.37-1_i386.deb.deb

Comment: @UneFemmeDouce You have typed `skype-ubuntu-precise_4.3.0.37-1_i386.deb.deb` but it should be `skype-ubuntu-precise_4.3.0.37-1_i386.deb`. You had added an extra ".deb".